# No independent clause in but...that

Tags: grammar

I came across a sentence in the New Yorker:

> But the evidence against talc had grown substantial enough by the time
> Berg was diagnosed **that** many U.S. manufacturers, including the
> makers of crayons, condoms, and surgical gloves, had erred on the side
> of caution and stopped using it in their products.

In this sentence, I do not find the independent clause (a clause that does not follow any conjunction). As far as I know, every sentence should contain an independent clause, like the clause before comma: I don't know her, but my husband does.

Is the "that" in bold a special usage with "but", in which case the sentence can leave out the independent clause?

Comment: The *But* at the start is a conjunction, but to an earlier sentence.  So the first part is the independent clause of this sentence.

Comment: And you should know that an independent clause is not defined as a clause that does not follow a conjunction.

Answer (score 1):

The independent clause is "the evidence had grown substantial enough".  The word "But" acts as an introductory linking word, connecting this to previous sentences.  It is not a subordinator.

In your other example, there are two independent clauses "I don't know her" and "my husband does". The word but acts as a coordinating conjunction linking two independent clauses.

Comment: I think it would be better to say that the sequence "the evidence had grown substantial enough" is only part of the independent clause, which I would take to be the whole sentence. I'd say that "but" is a coordinator; it belongs in main clause, which is functioning as at least the second coordinate in a coordinative construction.